# "pipewire-pulseaudio" and "pulseaudio" Conflicts in Fedora 38

Tags: linux, fedora, pulseaudio, pipewire

I am trying to use [easyeffect](https://github.com/wwmm/easyeffects) which needs the `pipewire-pulseaudio` package to be installed. I also want to use [PulseAudio Volume Control](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pavucontrol) (pavucontrol) which needs the `pulseaudio` package to be installed. These two packages have some conflicts. When I run `sudo dnf install pulseaudio`, gives me this error:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:48:53 ago on Thu 01 Jun 2023 10:14:30 PM +0330.
Error: 
 Problem: problem with installed package pipewire-pulseaudio-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64
  - package pipewire-pulseaudio-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64 from @System conflicts with pulseaudio provided by pulseaudio-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64 from fedora
  - package pipewire-pulseaudio-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64 from @System conflicts with pulseaudio-daemon provided by pulseaudio-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64 from fedora
  - package pulseaudio-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64 from fedora conflicts with pulseaudio-daemon provided by pipewire-pulseaudio-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64 from @System
  - package pipewire-pulseaudio-0.3.67-1.fc38.x86_64 from fedora conflicts with pulseaudio provided by pulseaudio-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64 from fedora
  - package pipewire-pulseaudio-0.3.67-1.fc38.x86_64 from fedora conflicts with pulseaudio-daemon provided by pulseaudio-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64 from fedora
  - package pulseaudio-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64 from fedora conflicts with pulseaudio-daemon provided by pipewire-pulseaudio-0.3.67-1.fc38.x86_64 from fedora
  - package pulseaudio-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64 from fedora conflicts with pulseaudio-daemon provided by pipewire-pulseaudio-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64 from updates
  - package pipewire-pulseaudio-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64 from updates conflicts with pulseaudio provided by pulseaudio-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64 from fedora
  - package pipewire-pulseaudio-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64 from updates conflicts with pulseaudio-daemon provided by pulseaudio-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64 from fedora
  - conflicting requests
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

I tried to use `--allow-erasing` but this will replace pulseaudio with pipewire-pulseaudio. What can I do about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Fedora has long transitioned to PipeWire permanently. If you want easyeffects you need to uninstall the PulseAudio server.

```
# rpm -qa | sort | grep -E -i "pipew|pulse|wire"
alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-1.2.7.1-5.fc38.i686
alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-1.2.7.1-5.fc38.x86_64
pipewire-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64
pipewire-alsa-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64
pipewire-devel-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64
pipewire-jack-audio-connection-kit-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64
pipewire-libs-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64
pipewire-pulseaudio-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64
pipewire-utils-0.3.71-2.fc38.x86_64
pulseaudio-libs-16.1-4.fc38.i686
pulseaudio-libs-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64
pulseaudio-libs-devel-16.1-4.fc38.i686
pulseaudio-libs-devel-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64
pulseaudio-libs-glib2-16.1-4.fc38.i686
pulseaudio-libs-glib2-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64
pulseaudio-utils-16.1-4.fc38.x86_64
wireplumber-0.4.14-1.fc38.x86_64
wireplumber-libs-0.4.14-1.fc38.x86_64
```